# Transform a unit cube to a frustum

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

i found this [example](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/08/060605.html) on how to to transform a unit cube into a frustum (truncated pyramid) via non-affine transformation. i need a matrix which can be pushed to my matrixstack which does the transform for me. how can this calculation

```
x' = (M11•x + M21•y + M31•z + OffsetX) ÷ (M14•x + M24•y + M34•z + M44)
y' = (M12•x + M22•y + M32•z + OffsetY) ÷ (M14•x + M24•y + M34•z + M44)
z' = (M13•x + M23•y + M33•z + OffsetZ) ÷ (M14•x + M24•y + M34•z + M44)
```

be expressed in a single matrix? is it possible?

for now i am using an inverse projection matrix to transform a unit cube into a frustum, but i have to divide every 3d point by w whenever i want to pick something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homogeneous matrix representing those equations is simply

```
       [ M11 M12 M13 M14 ]          [ 1 0 0 0 ]
  M =  [ M21 M22 M23 M24 ]  ,  M0 = [ 0 1 0 0 ]
       [ M31 M32 M33 M34 ]          [ 0 0 1 0 ]
       [ M41 M42 M43 M44 ]          [ 0 0 1 0 ]
```

You can simply multiply you model data `D` of the cube with it to get the truncated pyramid, as well as continue stacking with other matrices, such as camera + projection:

```
 ((M * D) * V ) * P;
```

There's no need to worry about the division by 'w' -- playing with the 4x4 matrices postpones that to the final stages of the rasterizer.

M0 here is the simplest projection matrix: however to utilize that, you must first transform you cube along the z-axis further away from the camera, multiply by M0 and transform it back to it's origin. Define a transform Matrix T.

```
       [ 1 0 0 0 ]
  T =  [ 0 1 0 0 ]
       [ 0 0 1 4 ]
       [ 0 0 0 0 ]
```

Then (D * T * M0 * (-T)) is a truncated pyramid, that just went through a perspective transform as if its center was 4 units away from the origin.

(Disclaimer: in opengl m43 is most likely -1)

Comment: what i need is the matrix M which represtens this `x' = (M11•x + M21•y + M31•z + OffsetX) ÷ (M14•x + M24•y + M34•z + M44)
y' = (M12•x + M22•y + M32•z + OffsetY) ÷ (M14•x + M24•y + M34•z + M44)
z' = (M13•x + M23•y + M33•z + OffsetZ) ÷ (M14•x + M24•y + M34•z + M44)` so i can just multiply it like you mentioned. when i mulitply M with my model data the divison is missing?!?!

Comment: If you want to get the 3D coordinates, then yes, you have to divide by w manually. (If you would simply like to render the pyramid, you don't) And btw. `M41 = OffsetX, M42 = OffsetY, M43 = OffsetZ;`

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the matrix it would be wise to choose a math library that is already implemented. The matrix is usually composed from a `projection_matrix * vies_matrix * world_transform_matrix`. All the three matrices can be created using a library such as [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/code.html) and the usage would be:

`glm::perspective(..args...) * glm::lookAt(..args..) * object_transformation`

In your case you could ignore `lookAt` and `object_transformation` and use only the projection to view the cube.

Comment: i already have such a math library. i can compute the projection matrix for a perspective projection. thing is, i want to just transform a unit cube to a frustum and project this via a orthogonal projection matrix. so i just need a matrix which can transform this mentioned cube to a frustum.